# What is DBL_MAX in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, max

I was looking at a program I found online and I see that the author used DBL_MAX in a few cases. I wasn't sure what it was so I researched a little, but there was not much explaining what it is and what its used for.

Can anyone explain what it is and why you should use it?

Some examples of use in the code were:

```
localT.maxTemp = -DBL_MAX;
double avg = -DBL_MAX;
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits

Comment: _I researched a little_ - or possibly not at all. Did you think to use Google? The first dozen results include a number of questions on this site that will answer your question.

Comment: I am stunned that anyone with the rep to vote to close this question would say that it's "unclear what you are asking."

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As it was said by others `DBL_MAX` defined in header `<cfloat>` in C++ or `<float.h>` in C is the value of maximum representable finite floating-point (double) number

In C++ you can get the same value using class `std::numeric_limits` defined in header `<limits>`

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
```

Here is an example of using the both approaches

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << DBL_MAX << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

At www.ideone.com (on-line C++ compiler) the output is

```
1.79769e+308
1.79769e+308
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a constant defined in `float.h` or `<cfloat>`. This header describes the characteristics of floating types for the specific system and compiler implemetation used.

`DBL_MAX` is maximum finite representable floating-point number.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits

Answer (score 0):

The `maximum finite representable floating-point number`.

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) if you find anything similar.

---