# Floating point over flow handling

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded, accumulator

I am currently working on a flow meter which calculates flow and calculates the the total that has been passed. Currently I am using double for flow calculation and I am accumulating it every second by `(total = total + current flow/3600)` where `total` is also of type double.

My question is what should be my maximum value check after which I can make total zero and start again. I am using C30 compiler for pic24.
here is my code.

```
double temp = info.FlowLast;        // info.FlowLast contains current flow 
temp /= 3600;                       // this routine is called after every 1 sec delay
info.Total += temp;                //info.Total Contains Totalizer value
info.FlowCounter +=temp;

if((uint16_t)(info.FlowCounter) >= 1)
{
    info.FlowCounter -= 1;      
    OS_Bsem_Set(BS_PULSE_COUNT);      //Pulse after every 1000kg of flow
}
```

Comment: And sometimes it stops accumulating when flow is very small and a power recycle reset is required

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include important information, such as code.

Comment: i have provided my code please have a look thanks.

Comment: What is the _actual_ problem ?

Comment: i dont understand when it will overflow so that i can make a roll over exceptio since it is very important.

Comment: It depends on your compiler and platform but typically `DBL_MAX` is `1.79769e+308`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278930/what-is-dbl-max-in-c

Comment: Also consider using [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: my compiler is Microchip C30 and double size is 32 bit. So if i put     if(info.Total >= DBL_MAX) 
    info.Total = 0;
it will work?

Comment: If `double` is really only 32 bits then I expect `DBL_MAX` == `FLT_MAX` == 1e37. But you would probably want to reset well before that.

Comment: sorry i cant understand your answer can you please eleborate it with a simple example it will be very helpful.

Comment: `Total >= DBL_MAX` makes no sense since `total` cannot be greater than DBL_MAX by definition.  And it is floating point - it will not "roll-over" - it may go to INF or NAN perhaps, but in actuality it will more likely just stop accumulating. When the accumulator becomes very large, the very small values you are adding will tend toward zero.  Eventually the differing magnitudes will be such that you add nothing and it will just stop accumulating.  For 32 bit fp for example `9000000.0 + 0.1 == 9000000.0"  Using fp for this is probably unnecessary, computationally expensive, and ill-advised.